# What is the difference between float2 and cuComplex, which to use?

Tags: c++, cuda, complex-numbers

I am trying to figure out how to use complex numbers in both my host and device code. I came across `cuComplex` (but can't find any documentation!) and `float2` which at least gets a mention in the CUDA programming guide.

What should I use? In the header file for `cuComplex`, it looks like the functions are declared with `__host__ __device__` so I am assuming that means that it would be ok to use them in either place.

My original data is being read in from a file into a `std::complex<float>` so I dont really want to mess with that. I guess in order to use the complex values on the GPU though, I will have to copy from the original `complex<float>` to the `cuComplex`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cuComplex` is defined in `/usr/local/cuda/include/cuComplex.h` (modulo your install dir). The relevant snippets:

```
typedef float2 cuFloatComplex;
typedef cuFloatComplex cuComplex;
typedef double2 cuDoubleComplex;
```

There are also handy functions in there for working with complex numbers -- multiplying them, building them, etc.

As for whether to use `float2` or `cuComplex`, you should use whichever is semantically appropriate -- is it a vector or a complex number? Also, if it is a complex number, you may want to consider using `cuFloatComplex` or `cuDoubleComplex` just to be fully explicit.

Comment: I have some other questions, I hope you could provide an answer. 1) Where is `float2` defined? 2) From your answer, `float2` and `cuComplex` are `typedef`s of each other, so I would say they are the same types. From the post [Complex Numbers](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/411477/complex-numbers/), it seems that `cuBLAS` functions would need `cuComplex` only and would not accept `float2`s. Is that right? 3) In the `include` file you mentioned, operations like sum, mul etc. are not defined as `operator` overloads. Does the same hold true also for `float2`? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to work with cuBLAS or cuFFT you should use cuComplex. If you're are going to write your own functions there should be no difference in performance as both are just a structure of two floats.

Comment: Yeah, I am working wtih my own functions which need complex values. What about the second question -  I guess there is no way around copying my original data (which comes from a 3rd party lib as a std::complex) will have to be copied into the cuComplex type right?

Comment: There's been some discussion whether `std::complex<float>` should be constrained such that it could be `reinterpret_cast` to a `float[2]`. This is already portable in practice.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, float2 is an array of 2 numbers. cuComplex (from the name alone) sounds like CUDA's complex format.

This post seems to point to where to find more on cuComplex: http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=81514